# Angular programmatic navigation - Why router does not in providers array

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-dependency-injection

In Angular Dependency Injector when ever we injecting a Type , we will includes them in providers array (May be in `@NgModule` decorator or `@Component` decorator. But in the following instance when we navigate programmatically we inject `Router` instance to constructor, But we don't provide in providers array as normally we do in Angular Dependency Injector.

What is the different here than Angular Dependency Injector ? for your reference I will attach both code

**Programmatic Navigation - Code**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLoadServer(){
    this.router.navigate(['servers']);
  }

}
```

**Angular Dependency Injector way - Code**

```
import { Component,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { LoggingService } from '../logging.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.css'],
  providers:[LoggingService]
})

export class AccountComponent {
  @Input() account: {name: string, status: string};
  @Input() id: number;

  constructor(private logginService:LoggingService){

  }
  
  onSetTo(status: string) {
    
 
    this.logginService.loggingStatusChange(status);
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RouterModule.forRoot already injects Router in root injector, thats why you don't have to include it in providers array any where. you can read about it here :-

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forroot

Comment: Yes, But we do that in imports array. not in providers array. is both same ?

Comment: if you import a module with providers in another module the services of that module becomes available automatically in your module. see source of router module here from line 121 :- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_module.ts